# how to copy a function over thousand of rows without losing cell spacing?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of rows

and every four rows I need to take an average of the cells in those rows `=AVERAGE(F2:F5)`

is there a code that will save me copy and pasting this formula every four rows?

I need the 3 rows between the averaged values to be blank also

e.g

```
averaged value
blank
blank
blank
averaged value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your data is in column *A*, then your first four values are in cells *A2* to *A5*. Then :

1. In cell *B5* the formula must be `=AVERAGE(A2:A5)`.
2. Select the cells *B2* to *B5*. Just like this:

[image]

3. Double click the little square dot on the corner of cell *B5* and the column *B* will be filled with the average and blank spaces.

Comment: this is great also I used this for something else.

Answer (score 1):

I guess row 1 will be a header label/name
use this formula in row 6 and copy down

=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,4)=0,"Avg = "&AVERAGE(T2:T5),"enter data")

then overwrite "enter data" cells with the data you want.